# <img srcset="..."> versus <picture><source>?

Tags: html, image, semantic-markup, responsive-images, srcset

I can't seem to discern a difference in function or meaning between using the `picture` element or just using the `img` element with the `srcset` attribute. I understand how they work; I just don't fully understand why or when to choose one over the other.

It looks like `img` element is lighter, cleaner code, but does it mean and do the same thing? I'm using this in my code to serve up different scaled versions of the same image:

```
<img src="default.jpg" 
srcset="image-800.jpg 800w, image-400.jpg 400w, image-200.jpg 200w" 
sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 12em" 
alt="something" />
```

It does exactly what I want as far as serving up the correct scaled image and it seems to work in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera.

I know that pretty much the same thing can be done with this code:

```
<picture>
<source srcset="image-800.jpg 800w, image-400.jpg 400w, image-200.jpg 200w" 
media="(max-width: 800px)" 
sizes="100vw" />
<source srcset="image-800.jpg 800w, image-400.jpg 400w, image-200.jpg 200w" 
media="(min-width: 800px)" 
sizes="12em" />
<img src="default.jpg" alt="something" />
</picture>
```

So, what's the difference functionally? Why would I use more code to do essentially the same thing?

Is there a semantic difference? What would that be?

From [w3.org `img`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element):

> An `img` element represents an image and its fallback content.

Also from [w3.org `picture`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-picture-element):

> The `picture` element is a container which provides multiples sources to
>   its contained img element to allow authors to declaratively control or
>   give hints to the user agent about which image resource to use, based
>   on the screen pixel density, viewport size, image format, and other
>   factors. It represents its children.

If the `srcset` attribute already does this for the `img` element, why do we need a `picture` element as a container? What am I missing? Is there a difference in semantic meaning?

I read [one other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750594/can-i-use-img-srcset-or-picture-for-image-size-rather-than-viewport-size) on here with a comment that suggested that `srcset` on the `img` element was simply new and not completely reliable crossbrowser. Is that still true? Was that the only difference?

Comment: One important reason for the existence of `<picture>` is to allow images with different *formats* instead of just different sizes, à la `<video>`/`<audio>`. You could prefer to serve a slightly smaller WebP on Chrome and fall back on a different format for other browsers, for example. In the future, there should be more and better formats, supported by more browsers.

Comment: Ah. Thank you Ry. I guess I overlooked instances where someone might want to serve up different image formats as opposed to merely serving up different pixel sizes. Would it then make sense to continue using img when serving different resolutions of the same image in the same format and to use picture when serving multiple formats?
Also.. is it ok to reply to comments/responses like I just did?

Comment: Yes, I think it would make sense to keep using `<img srcset>` when not serving different formats. And… it should be okay to reply to comments like that, but I didn’t get a notification this time for some reason. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `<picture>` is useless, because you want to show the same image content everywhere.

`<picture>` is mandatory when you want to perform Art Direction, for example change the image width/height ratio when you hit a breakpoint, or crop the image to zoom in when you're on a small device.

Answer (score 2):

Alongside art direction a use case for using `<picture>` is when you want to serve a different filetype. For example, Chrome supports `webp` which has better compression than JPG. The only way to have Chrome pick a `webp` file is by providing it through `<picture>`.

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="image-800.webp 800w, image-400.webp 400w, image-200.webp 200w" 
type='image/webp' media="(max-width: 800px)" 
sizes="100vw" />
    <img src="default.webp" alt="something" />
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that `<picture>` opens up the possibility for solving future problems, there is so much potential it can do, but for most of the time what you will actually do can be implemented with supercharged `<img>` with the added `srcset`.

Like choosing between beef pc with high end graphic card and portable gaming console.